# How to add external library to Homebrew ffmpeg install?

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, homebrew

I successfully installed ffmpeg through Homebrew. I want to add additional libraries/codecs.

> FFmpeg can be hooked up with a number of external libraries to add
>   support for more formats. None of them are used by default, their use
>   has to be explicitly requested by passing the appropriate flags to
>   ./configure

Can someone please explain how to 'hook up' an external library to ffmpeg?
For example:

> Go to http://www.twolame.org/ and follow the instructions for
>   installing the library. Then pass --enable-libtwolame to configure to
>   enable it

And there, at twolame the install instructions are:

> ./configure 
>   make 
>   make install

There's no configure file in the ffmpeg directory.
Where should the external library (in this case twolame) be installed?
Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

brew has options you can set type `brew options ffmpeg` then you can do thing like `brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac`.

But, there is no twolame option. You can modify the brew formula like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939651/how-to-modify-a-homebrew-formula

Comment: I don't think there are brew options for most of the external libraries ffmpeg supports. Still looking for a simple straight-forward workflow for getting them in there but you've given me some clues I hadn't explored. Thank You! (Alas, until I have 15 points I can't up vote.)